# Python data frame apply filter on multiple columns with same condition?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, multiple-columns

Here is my pandas data frame.

```
new_data =

    name   duration01        duration02          orz01      orz02     
    ABC   1 years 6 months    5 months           Nan        Google     
    XYZ   4 months            3 years 2 months   Google      Zensar      
    TYZ   4 months            4 years            Google In   Google   
    OPI   2 months            3 months           Nan       accenture    
    NRM   9 months            3 years            Google      Zensar
```

I want to find out the name of employees who works in Google and there duration in months.Here the value contains in the multiple columns ? How to apply filter on multiple columns ?

duration01 => orz01 ( how many months/years employee spend in orz01)
duration02 => orz02 ( how many months/years employee spend in orz02)

There are total 10 orz and 10 respective duration columns.

I tried below code

```
# Selected the required columns
orz_cols = new_data.columns[new_data.columns.str.contains('orz')]

new_data [ new_data[orz_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Google')) ]
```

But its not printing proper data ?

How do I achieve this

I want output like below

```
name  Total_duration_in Google_in_Months
ABC   5 months
XYZ   4 months
TYZ   52 months
```

Using the first part what @Stefan gave I did below part to convert years to months

```
# filter the data

Google_Data = dt1[dt1['orz'].str.contains('Google')]

dur = []

for i in range(0,len(Google_Data['duration'])):
    dur.append(Google_Data['duration'][i].split())

months_list = []

for i in range(0,len(dur)):
    #print dur[i]
    if dur[i][1] == 'years':
        if len(dur[i]) > 2:
            val1 = int(dur[i][0]) * 12 + int(dur[i][2])
            val11 = str(val1)+" months"
            months_list.append(val11)
        else:
            val2 = int(dur[i][0]) * 12
            val22 = str(val2)+" months"
            months_list.append(val22)
    else:
        val3 = dur[i][0]+" months"
        months_list.append(val3)

months_list[:3]

# Concat
df2 = pd.DataFrame(months_list,index=Google_Data.index.copy())

Google_duration = pd.concat([Google_Data, df2], axis=1)


Output :

                    organization                      Duration_In_Months
name        
Aparna Arora        Google Headstrong Capital Markets   60 months
Aparna Dasgupta     Google                              24 months
Aparna Dhar         Google India Ltd                    56 months
```

Now I want to perform final step i.e. take the sum by grouping the name but here 'name' is index. I am struggling to get the sum.

Here what i am trying

```
# Splitting the Duration_In_Months to get only number values
# Its returning the type as 'str'

Google_duration1 = Google_duration.Duration_In_Months.apply(lambda x : x.split()[0])

# apply groupby

Genpact_dur2.index.groupby(Genpact_dur2['Duration_In_Months'])
```

How do I Groupby index and take the sum ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

Set `index` and get `columns` to combine:

```
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)    
orz_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('orz')]
duration_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('duration')]
merge_cols = zip(orz_cols, duration_cols)
```

Use `pd.concat()` to reshape and rename:

```
long_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, cols].rename(columns={col: col[:-2] for col in orz_cols + duration_cols}) for cols in merge_cols])
```

Eliminate non-Google `orz` entries:

```
long_df = long_df[long_df.orz.str.contains('Google')]
```

Calculcate `duration` depending on `month` & `year`:

```
long_df.duration = long_df.duration.str.split().apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) if x[1] == 'months' else int(x[0]) * 12)
```

Sum by `name`:

```
long_df.groupby(level='name')['duration'].sum()
      duration
name          
ABC          5
NRM          9
TYZ         52
XYZ          4
```

Comment: He wants a result groupby().sum()

Comment: plus string parsing.

Comment: I didn't want to mention it because it's not about pandas. You shouldn't carry him baby completely :)

Comment: @Stefan First part is working fine but I am getting an error in second part    `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'less'`

Comment: `Google = dt1[dt1['organization'].str.contains('Google')]`  I filtered the data for orz

Comment: Yes if you have non-string values in the orz cols then need to concert to str first. Also better to vectorize, I was mor focusing on the other parts. Any further questions?

Comment: @Stefan thanks again.  I did edit the question by further adding the code which I did. Now I am struggling to apply the GroupBy on index column. How do I apply GroupBy. A little help would be helpful.

Comment: Will look at it a little later today

Comment: I tried for second part but I was getting an error. I also tried with lambda, apply but couldn't get anything. I was facing same issue of data type.It might be due to data issue so went for traditional approach of if else and filter.         ok no problem.

Comment: for `.groupby()` on `index` use `.groupby(level=0)` if you only have one column (or the name of the index if it has one). With `MultiIndex`, it becomes `.groupby(level=['index_name_1', 'index_name_2'])`. Then `.sum()` of result.

Comment: One  question would it be possible to check the 'contains' for 'Google' word instead of checking equality while taking the Groupby.Because there are other extra words also present.
I tried to check contains

`# SUM DURATION AND OUTPUT DF
    gen_data1 = gen_data1[gen_data1['organization'].str.contains('Genpact')].groupby(['name','organization']).sum().reset_index()    
    gen_data1 = gen_data1[['name','actual_dur']]
    gen_data1.columns = ['name', 'Total_duration_in Genpact_in_Months'] `  

but getting an error.

Comment: I just took another look and simplified a bit. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reshaping using [pandas.melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), then conditionally parsing out values for years and months using `np.where()`. Finally, aggregate by the *Google* organization.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

...
# LIST OF SUBSET COLUMNS
durationCols = [c for c in df.columns if 'duration' in c ]
orzCols = [c for c in df.columns if 'orz' in c ]

# MELT AND MERGE
df = pd.merge(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name'], value_vars=durationCols,
                  var_name=None, value_name='duration'),
              pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name'], value_vars=orzCols,
                  var_name=None, value_name='orz'),
              right_index=True, left_index=True, on=['name'])[['name', 'duration', 'orz']]

# DURATION CONDITIONAL CALCULATION (YEAR + MONTH)
df['actual_dur'] = np.where(df['duration'].str.contains('year'),
                            df['duration'].str[:1], 0).astype(int) * 12 + \
                   np.where(df['duration'].str.contains('year.*month'),
                            df['duration'].str[8:9],
                            np.where(df['duration'].str.contains('month'),
                                     df['duration'].str[:1], 0)).astype(int)

df['orz'] = np.where(df['orz']\
                     .str.contains('Google'), 'Google', df['orz'])    

# SUM DURATION AND OUTPUT DF
df = df[df['orz']=='Google'].groupby(['name','orz']).sum().reset_index()    
df = df[['name','actual_dur']]
df.columns = ['name', 'Total_duration_in Google_in_Months']
```

Output

```
#   name  Total_duration_in Google_in_Months
# 0  ABC                                   5
# 1  NRM                                   9
# 2  TYZ                                  52
# 3  XYZ                                   4
```

Comment: thanks its working fine but i am getting odd value after year to month calculation step. Below is the value for particular name.

Comment: Possibly working with actual data causes issues. Does duration contain content other than single numbers in years/months? Possibly multiple digits?

Comment: I  have  changed  this part bit `df['duration'].str[:1], 0).astype(int) * 12` to ` df['duration'].str[:2], 0).astype(int) * 12` so it handles double digit like 10 or 11 but the odd value i am getting is for duration entry like '2 years'.

Comment: Actually I am replacing 'Nan' and 'Present' entries in duration column by '1 year' and '2 year' respectively before calculation. However those values  weren't giving an odd value. I will check again and let you know. I think some data issue causing the problem like 'month' and 'year' has many names in other languages.I am replacing those values using replace but there are many  such different names. I was wondering is there any python calender dict so i just look and replace those in English language.Sorry for asking this question here. Script is working fine. I accept the answer. Thanks.